# ClearCase Checkin trigger doesn't allow deliver

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I created a preop checkin trigger that checks the comment to make sure it isn't empty.  This works just fine.

However, when I do a deliver from the dev stream to the int stream, the trigger stops at the check in process.  Is there a way around this?  I am assuming that the comments while checking in for a deliver process are blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a preop trigger on the `deliver_start` operation kind (opkind) in order to set an environment variable which would act as a flag.

When that environment variable is set, your original script (the preop checkin one) could simply return true (ie does nothing and allows the checkin to proceed)

Another postop trigger on `deliver_cancel` and `deliver_complete` opkinds will cancel that environment variable.

See an [example of pre and postop trigger on deliver events here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_u_trg_dlvr_stup_s.htm).